# ActiveRecord Get Max Value Without Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to get the last record with a certain value, but without loading it.

I have to do something like:

```
Thing.where(cool: true).where(created_at: Thing.where(cool: true).maximum(:created_at))
```

The above is a way to do it, but it does a 2nd query to get the maximum value first. I want to do it all in one query and get the SQL equivalent of something = max(etc).

Just before someone mentions it: *.last* doesn't work because it returns an object not a relation.

In order words, I need to do *.last* but returning a relation instead of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Thing.where("cool=1 AND created_at=(SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM things WHERE cool=1)")
```

On Rails 7, when I tested your query, the database is queried only once.

Comment: writing it raw sequel works yea. How would I do it if Thing was instead @something.things

Because that's the issue I got. I don't know how to refer to the collection of things easily when its picked up by model defined relations without writing some arguably long sql

Comment: If I can come up with any other solution to this problem, I will let you know.